# Mapping clr namespace to xaml namespace with using keyword

Tags: xaml, namespaces

I have used the **clr-namespace** token to map a xaml namespace to a clr namespace as in

*xamlns:local = "clr-namespace:mycompany.myproject"*

In the above example, the **local** is mapped to **mycompany.myproject**.

I have seen the use of the token **using** in some code.

*xamlns:local = "using:mycompany.myproject"*

Is there any difference in behavior when using the token **using** compared to **clr-namespace**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone xaml we use "clr-namespace" token to map a xaml namespace. Where as in Windows Store app (winrt) we use "using" token to map a xaml namespace.